# ssh into a server that has a broken bash install

Tags: shell, ssh, login, tmux

I think I broke the installation of ncurses on my Arch Linux VPS. Now I can't login with SSH, I get this error:

```
$ ssh me@xyz.com
Last login: Mon Oct 26 08:56:59 2015 from 0.0.0.0
-bash: error while loading shared libraries: libncursesw.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Connection to xyz.com closed.
```

I'm not really sure what to do now. I have a tmux session running on the server. Is there maybe some way I can attach to it from my local machine by forwarding ports or something?

Comment: I don't think so. SSH runs every command in bash so if this one is broken, I don't see any solution.

Comment: You can use sftp to re-upload the necessary libraries...

Comment: @Jan stfp is not working, Filezilla says "unexpected EOF" and my sftp program simply says "connection closed" when trying to log in

Comment: @nanny Then you are almost dead (uh, looks like ssh uses the shell to open up sftp)… Unless by chance you found another SSH session still on.

Comment: Are there any other users on that system who have a shell other than bash?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Yes, but they are broken with the same error. I may have found a work-around, I'm going add it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to my VPS hosting provider (DigitalOcean), I was able to boot into an Arch ISO, mount my system's partition, and perform a system upgrade with `pacman` like this:

```
$ mount /dev/vda1 /mnt/arch
$ pacman --root /mnt/arch --cachedir /mnt/arch/var/cache/pacman/pkg --config /mnt/arch/etc/pacman.conf -Syyu
```

which fixed the problem.

Moral of the story: **don't do partial upgrades on Arch Linux.**

Answer (score 1):

If your login shell won't even start then you cannot log in. The client sends a string to the server and it's up to the user's login shell on the server to interpret the string. The client has no way to tell the server “run some other command instead”.

This is a security mechanism: if a user's shell is restricted in what it can do, then the user can't do anything that it doesn't permit.

If you've blocked access to all the accounts on the system, then you'll have to use some method that bypasses normal logins, such as physical access or a recovery console.

Some tips:

- When doing maintenance, always keep a root shell open and don't close it until you've tested that everything works.
- Install a statically-linked shell on an account with sudoer rights. I don't see any prepackaged by Arch. [Debian has a few](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208278/trying-to-transplant-bash-to-mnt-for-chroot-what-does-bash-want-in-order-to-wo/208383#208383); you could just copy the executable and add it to `/etc/shells`.
- Make sure that you have a way to get root even if some things are broken; either set root's shell to `bash-static` or `sash` something similar, or set up a [toor account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/105346/root-access-that-cant-change-root-password/105363#105363) (alternate way for root to log in). Keep in mind that `sudo` could break too; you may want to have an emergency password on the toor account that's randomly generated (unique and not memorized) and written down on a piece of paper that you keep in a safe.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try:

> ssh -t username@hostname /bin/sh

Also you can try copy by scp missing libncursesw.so.5 to your remote.

Comment: ssh runs commands via the shell, so your line would end up being run as something like `bash -c /bin/sh`, so that won't work.

Comment: Also scp is throwing the same error.

Comment: Hm.. what with sshfs ? Also doesn't work?

Comment: @nanny Oh if really everything goes through bash then I see no solution whatsoever.